# MongoDB Performance Issues With RegEx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

So here is the problem. I have around 1 million documents in my Item collection, which is structured something like this:

```
{
    "id": "04404a89-f05a-11e6-931b-ecb1d7f39a05",
    "name": "LX SUPER COMFORT",
    "sku": "40110",
    "brand": "Luxury",
    "brendNumber": "LX-0001",
    "inStock": 100

}
```

Now I want to get all my items, where either "name" field or "sku", or "brand" or "brandNumber" contains a certain substring, like "LX" for example. In addition to that there is also one condition that just checks if "inStock" is greater than zero.

So what I did is that:

```
  const conditions = {}

  // for testing 
  const query = "LX"
  const onlyInStock = 'true' 
  const startIndex = 0;
 
  const searchValue = {
    $regex: new RegExp(['.*', query, '.*'].join(''), 'i'),
  }

  conditions.$or = [
    { name: searchValue },
    { sku: searchValue },
    { brend: searchValue },
    { brendNumber: searchValue },
  ]

  if (onlyInStock && onlyInStock.toLowerCase() === 'true')
    conditions.inStock = { $gt: 0 }

  result = await Item.find(conditions).limit(25).skip(startIndex)
```

But this is obviously not the best approach since it takes around 10 seconds till I get just 25 documents I need. So how should I write my query?

Comment: Regex queries are tough. OR queries are also tough. You may need to look at denormalization (store the searchable fields in a combined field) and/or full text indexing (which won't do the exact same regex search but is useful for keywords).

Comment: Might be a good idea. I'll try to create a new field that will store all other fields values.